# Como funciona a integração de aplicativos em redes sociais?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, app, oauth

Ultimamente tem se tornado cada vez mais comum a integração de aplicativos dos mais diversos tipos em redes sociais, como por exemplo Facebook, Twitter e até mesmo o Github. Queria entender como funciona essa integração. O Gitter por exemplo permite interação via chat em repositórios do Github... No Facebook, qualquer pessoa pode ir na seção de desenvolvedores e criar um aplicativo para interagir com páginas e pessoas. Até mesmo o Google Hangouts tem aplicativos para serem usados a gosto do usuário na hora das conferências. Estou muito curioso à respeito do funcionamento disso.

Como eu poderia reproduzir algo desse tipo em uma aplicação? Essas plataformas simplesmente fornecem uma API para que essas apps adicionais possam ser integradas? Ou tem algo além disso? Referências para leitura são muito bem vindas... :D

Answer (score 1):

O protocolo utilizado para integrações de aplicações é o O-Auth. Nunca implementei ele do lado da minha aplicação, apenas ja testei o uso da integração com aplicações como as citadas na sua questão.

Também até a pouco não sabia que se tratava de um padrão para autenticação de clientes externos a aplicações. O site que tem toda a documentação é:
http://oauth.net/2/

Espera ter ajudado!